# onYouTubePlayerReady not getting called

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the [Youtube JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) and swfobject to embed a video, and `onYouTubePlayerReady` is never getting called. What's going on? Here's my code:

```html
<div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>
<script>
    // Inject YouTube API script
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/player_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var VIDEO_ID='<?php echo $video_id; ?>';
    var params = {
        'allowFullScreen': 'true',
        'allowScriptAccess': 'always',
        'allownetworking': 'internal'
    };
    var atts = {
        'class': 'bilingual-video',
        'id': 'ytapiplayer'
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        'http://www.youtube.com/v/' +
            VIDEO_ID +
            '?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytapiplayer&version=3' +
            '&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&controls=0',
            'ytapiplayer', '500', '400', '8', null, null, params, atts);
</script>

<script>
var ytplayer;
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById('ytapiplayer');
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `allownetworking` set to 'internal'; by definition, this does not let the SWF communicate with anything via Flash's `ExternalInterface` API. However, the YouTube javascript API relies on ExternalInterface, so in effect you've blocked the SWF's access to the API.

If you remove that parameter, it should start calling the `onYouTubePlayerReady` function again.

Comment: Interesting, I have that parameter set to internal because I don't want people to be able to click the YouTube link and go to the YouTube url. Is there another way to prevent that?

Comment: I'll use the iframe API and try to prevent the click from there.